# ¿Es correcto crear una clase con metodos estaticos para conectarse a una base de datos MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy empezando a aprender php y MySQL y tengo la duda de si es correcto crear una clase con metodos estaticos para la conexion. La clase que he creado es esta:

```
class ConexionBD
{

    private static $conexionBD;

    public static function conectar()
    {
        self::$conexionBD = new mysqli(
            'localhost', 
            'root', 
            'pass', 
            'nombreBD');

            if (self::$conexionBD->connect_error) {
                die('Error de Conexión (' . self::$conexionBD->connect_errno . ') '
                        . self::$conexionBD->connect_error);
            }
    }

    public static function getConexion(){
        return self::$conexionBD;

    }

    public static function cerrarConexion(){
        self::$conexionBD->close();
    }
}
```

La duda viene a raiz de que no se si en una web por ejemplo , se trabaja con una sola conexion en todas las operaciones con la base de datos o hace falta crear una clase capaz de crear varias instancias de conexiones... necesito un poco de orientacion.

Comment: En realidad cada operacion deberia hacerlo sobre su propia conexion, asi la DB maneja un pool de conexiones y acelera las que pueda y no se traba con ninguna.

Comment: Entonces no tiene ningun sentido lo que he  hecho y lo que tengo que hacer una clase que instancie conexiones y se las pase a cada operación para que BD trabaje simultáneamente con todas ellas.

Comment: lo unico que te puedo recomendar que ya PHP 7 fue deprecada la palabra [static](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php), y por ende sebes tener cuidado con esto!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que estás intentando hacer supongo que es implementar un patrón singleton para la conexión, en cuyo caso debiera ser:

```
class ConexionBD
{
    private static $instance;

    private static function conectar()
    {
        $conn = new mysqli(
            'localhost', 
            'root', 
            'pass', 
            'nombreBD');

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die('Error de Conexión ('.$conn->connect_errno.') '.$conn->connect_error);
        }
        return $conn;
    }

    public static function getConexion(){
        if(!self::$instance) {
          self::$instance = self::conectar();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Y usar la conexión en otras clases como

```
$conn = ConexionBD::getConexion();
```

De esa manera te asegurarías de que al llamar muchas veces a `ConexionBD::getConexion()` siempre te devolviera la misma conexión, y de esa manera poder abrir una transacción en un método y commitear en otro método. Por otro lado, si realmente quisieras asegurarte de que la conexión fuera siempre la misma, tendrías que sobreescribir el `magic_method` `__clone` para que no dejara clonar la conexión:

```
public function __clone() {
    throw new Exception("No se puede clonar esta clase");
}
```

Y, de paso, asegurarte de que el constructor de la clase es privado para que nadie haga, sin querer `new ConexionBD()`

```
private function __contruct() {}
```

Ahora bien, **usar el patrón singleton en PHP es considerado un antipatrón**. Por ejemplo si quieres hacer tests unitarios, cada test usaría la misma conexión y estaría influenciado por las operaciones que haya hecho el test anterior. Eso contradice el concepto mismo de un text unitario.

No existen los pools de conexiones en PHP (en el sentido que PHP le pegue a un servicio permanentemente abierto que mantiene varias conexiones y se persiste entre requests) sino que cada cliente que entra creará su propia conexión y ésta se cerrará automáticamente cuando finalice el ciclo de vida del request. En este sentido sí ocurre una suerte de pooling como dice [gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi), pero no es un pool persistente como ocurre en una app de Python o Node.js. PHP recrea la app en cada request.

No tienes cómo hacer que dos clientes que ingresan a tu app usen la misma conexión, y eso en realidad es bueno, porque un cliente podría abrir una transacción y otro cliente invocar un método que ejecuta un COMMIT. Sería bastante malo que un tercero le hiciera COMMIT a tu transacción cuando estás insertando registros en bulk. Por lo mismo, en realidad no es tan terrible instanciar una nueva conexión en cada controller. De nuevo, como dijo [gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi), esto permitiría manejar dos o más conexiones en un mismo controller y (caso rebuscado) usar una conexión para leer de una tabla y otra para insertar en otra tabla.

```
$resultado = $conn1->query('SELECT nombre, apellido from clientes where region=1');
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT into clientes_region1 (nombre,apellido) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $nombre, $apellido);

while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
    $nombre = $row['nombre'];
    $apellido = $row['apellido'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Por el principio de única responsabilidad, el controller debiera abrir su conexión (y opcionalmente cerrarla) sin depender de una conexión global.

Si necesitas que dos métodos de el mismo controller usen la misma conexión, entonces instancia la conexión como una variable de la clase al hacer __construct del controller.

```
class Ejemplo {
  private $conexion;

  public function __construct() {
       $this->conexión = new mysqli(...);
  }
}
```

Y si necesitas que una clase le pase su instancia de conexión a otra clase, hazlo con inyección de dependencias: instancia la segunda clase pasándole a su constructor la instancia de conexión que ya tienes.

```
class Padre {
  private $conexion;
  private $hijo;

  public function __construct() {
       $this->conexión = new mysqli(...);
       $this->hijo = new Hijo($this->conexion);
  }
}
```

De esa manera, si quieres hacer tests unitarios de la clase `Hijo`, creas la conexión en el test, instancias la clase, ejecutas el test, cierras la conexión.

**EDIT** ¿Es opcional cerrar la conexión?

Respuesta corta: sí, es opcional. La conexión se cerrará cuando el ciclo de vida del request termine. PEEEERO... **hay casos de borde.**

Supongamos que tu aplicación tenga requests muy largos. Por ejemplo, lee de una tabla de 500.000 registros, los mete en un array, los procesa, los guarda en un archivo, sube ese archivo a un servidor remoto, etc (provisto que tus parámetros de memoria y tiempo límite de ejecución soporten esto) y ese proceso dura en total 10 minutos.

En este caso tú necesitas tener la conexión abierta sólo para leer esos 500.000 registros de la tabla. El resto de los 10 minutos sigue abierta sólo porque el request no ha terminado. La conexión queda "tomada" y la base de datos sólo soporta un número limitado de conexiones simultáneas (esto es configurable, pero igual es un número finito). Para ese caso de uso sí sería oportuno cerrar la conexión apenas trajiste los datos de la tabla para liberar conexiones de la base de datos y así no bloquear a otros usuarios.

Comment: Una perfecta explicacion que me ha ayudado a resolver mi duda solo tengo una mas respecto a tu respuesta. Dices que el cierre de la conexion por parte del controller es opcional. ¿Quiere decir eso que puedo despreocuparme de cerrar las conexiones en el controlador ya que se cerraran solas igualmente? @amenadiel

Comment: Voy a editar mi respuesta para añadir eso